# Errors when Compiling Cygwin in Visual Studio with VisualGDB

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opengl, cygwin

I am trying to compile a Cygwin project in Visual Studio, using VisualGDB.
When compiling, it printed out:

> 1>/bin/sh ../../../libtool --mode=link g++  -g -Wall    -o
>   expression.exe  SimpleFace.o ExpressionUI.o  global.o noise.o
>   simulation.o  actor.o Bone.o MathLib.o  maxMesh.o skeleton.o saflist.o
>   bmptexture.o RenderTool.o interface.o  FileUtils.o
>   -L../../../src/expression/ExpressionLib -lexpression -L../../../sdk/nvmathlib/src/nv_math -lnvmath **-lglui  -lglut  -lGL  -lGLU**
>
> 1>g++ -g -Wall -o expression.exe SimpleFace.o ExpressionUI.o global.o
>   noise.o simulation.o actor.o Bone.o MathLib.o maxMesh.o skeleton.o
>   saflist.o bmptexture.o RenderTool.o interface.o FileUtils.o 
>   -L/cygdrive/c/Users/ASTAR/Desktop/ExpDemo1.2_linux/src/expression/ExpressionLib
>   /cygdrive/c/Users/ASTAR/Desktop/ExpDemo1.2_linux/src/expression/ExpressionLib/.libs/libexpression.a
>   -L/cygdrive/c/Users/ASTAR/Desktop/ExpDemo1.2_linux/sdk/nvmathlib/src/nv_math
>   /cygdrive/c/Users/ASTAR/Desktop/ExpDemo1.2_linux/sdk/nvmathlib/src/nv_math/.libs/libnvmath.a
>   -lglui /usr/lib/libglut.dll.a /usr/lib/libXi.dll.a /usr/lib/libXrandr.dll.a /usr/lib/libXext.dll.a
>   /usr/lib/libXrender.dll.a /usr/lib/libX11.dll.a /usr/lib/libxcb.dll.a
>   /usr/lib/libXau.dll.a /usr/lib/libXdmcp.dll.a **-lGL -lGLU**

And, there are a lot of errors such as

> 1>/usr/lib/w32api/libglui.a(glui.o):glui.cpp:(.text+0x4e): **undefined
>   reference to** `_glutGetWindow@0'
>   1>/usr/lib/w32api/libglui.a(glui.o):glui.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined
>   reference to`_glutGetWindow@0'
>   1>/usr/lib/w32api/libglui.a(glui.o):glui.cpp:(.text+0x129): undefined
>   reference to `_glutInitWindowPosition@8'
>   1>/usr/lib/w32api/libglui.a(glui.o):glui.cpp:(.text+0x19a): undefined
>   reference to`_glDrawBuffer@4'
>   1>/usr/lib/w32api/libglui.a(glui.o):glui.cpp:(.text+0x206): undefined
>   reference to `_glutCreateSubWindow@20'
>   1>/usr/lib/w32api/libglui.a(glui.o):glui.cpp:(.text+0x254): undefined
>   reference to`_glDrawBuffer@4'
>   1>/usr/lib/w32api/libglui.a(glui.o):glui.cpp:(.text+0x2e7): undefined
>   reference to `_glutEntryFunc@4'...

I think the problem is the second command **g++** missing **-lglut**.
But I don't know how to add these because the command is auto-generated by VisualGDB.

Anyone has suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`glui` is built on top of WGL (the Windows/GDI OpenGL32); this is not compatible with GLX (the X11 OpenGL provided by Mesa).  You have to pick one or the other.